# How to scrape Dynamic Web pages when bs4 and other python libraries do not work?

Tags: python, html, css, automation

I am scraping this website:  https://www.eafo.eu/alternative-fuels/electricity/charging-infra-stats

I am unable to pull the dynamic chart values using bs4 or Selenium.  I can get the html but no data values.  When I use Selenium I am able to capture the html but without the data.  Is there anything I am missing to grab this or a stronger tool that can manipulate dynamic web [image]pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the six charts on the page are populated with data from individual API calls which can be found under the network settings of your browser. You can send requests to these endpoints yourself and parse the responses:

```
import urllib.parse, requests, json
headers = {'authority': 'www.eafo.eu', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"', 'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36', 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin', 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty', 'referer': 'https://www.eafo.eu/alternative-fuels/electricity/charging-infra-stats', 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'cookie': 'yearFilter=2020; activeSubMenu=electricity; subMenuActiveItem=charging_infra_stats; fuelFilter=Electricity; _ga=GA1.2.1782486955.1628797896; _gid=GA1.2.47726291.1628797896; _gat_gtag_UA_129775638_1=1'}
params = (('compare', 'false'),)
urls = ['https://www.eafo.eu/normal-and-fast-charge-points/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false', 'https://www.eafo.eu/charging-positions-per-10-evs/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false', 'https://www.eafo.eu/normal-power-charging-positions/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false', 'https://www.eafo.eu/fillingstations-electricity-top-5/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false', 'https://www.eafo.eu/fast-charging/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false', 'https://www.eafo.eu/top-5-countries-charging-positions-per-10-evs/-1/-1/-1/false/false/nvt?compare=false'] 
data = [[urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[1], json.loads(requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).text)] for url in urls]
result = {a:[[i['c'][0]['v'], i['c'][1]['v']] for i in b['data']['rows']] for a, b in data}
```

Output:

```
{'normal-and-fast-charge-points': [[2008, 0], [2009, 0], [2010, 0], [2011, 13], [2012, 257], [2013, 751], [2014, 1474], [2015, 3396], [2016, 5190], [2017, 8723], [2018, 11138], [2019, 15136], [2020, 24987]], 'charging-positions-per-10-evs': [['2008', 0], ['2009', 0], ['2010', '14'], ['2011', '6'], ['2012', '3'], ['2013', '4'], ['2014', '5'], ['2015', '5'], ['2016', '5'], ['2017', '5'], ['2018', '6'], ['2019', '7'], ['2020', '9']], 'normal-power-charging-positions': [['2008', 0], ['2009', 0], ['2010', 400], ['2011', 2379], ['2012', 10250], ['2013', 17093], ['2014', 24917], ['2015', 44786], ['2016', 70012], ['2017', 97287], ['2018', 107446], ['2019', 148880], ['2020', 199250]], 'fillingstations-electricity-top-5': [['Netherlands', 66461], ['France', 45413], ['Germany', 43633], ['Sweden', 13564], ['Italy', 13214]], 'fast-charging': [['2008', 0], ['2009', 0], ['2010', 0], ['2011', 13], ['2012', 257], ['2013', 751], ['2014', 1474], ['2015', 3396], ['2016', 5190], ['2017', 8723], ['2018', 11138], ['2019', 15136], ['2020', 24987]], 'top-5-countries-charging-positions-per-10-evs': [['Latvia', '3.15'], ['Slovakia', '4.34'], ['Croatia', '5.14'], ['Estonia', '5.31'], ['Netherlands', '5.71']]}
```

In a cleaner JSON format:

```
t = {' '.join(map(str.capitalize, a.split('-'))):b for a, b in result.items()}
print(json.dumps(t, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Normal And Fast Charge Points": [
        [
            2008,
            0
        ],
        [
            2009,
            0
        ],
        [
            2010,
            0
        ],
        [
            2011,
            13
        ],
        [
            2012,
            257
        ],
        [
            2013,
            751
        ],
        [
            2014,
            1474
        ],
        [
            2015,
            3396
        ],
        [
            2016,
            5190
        ],
        [
            2017,
            8723
        ],
        [
            2018,
            11138
        ],
        [
            2019,
            15136
        ],
        [
            2020,
            24987
        ]
    ],
    "Charging Positions Per 10 Evs": [
        [
            "2008",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2009",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2010",
            "14"
        ],
        [
            "2011",
            "6"
        ],
        [
            "2012",
            "3"
        ],
        [
            "2013",
            "4"
        ],
        [
            "2014",
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "2015",
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "2016",
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "2017",
            "5"
        ],
        [
            "2018",
            "6"
        ],
        [
            "2019",
            "7"
        ],
        [
            "2020",
            "9"
        ]
    ],
    "Normal Power Charging Positions": [
        [
            "2008",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2009",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2010",
            400
        ],
        [
            "2011",
            2379
        ],
        [
            "2012",
            10250
        ],
        [
            "2013",
            17093
        ],
        [
            "2014",
            24917
        ],
        [
            "2015",
            44786
        ],
        [
            "2016",
            70012
        ],
        [
            "2017",
            97287
        ],
        [
            "2018",
            107446
        ],
        [
            "2019",
            148880
        ],
        [
            "2020",
            199250
        ]
    ],
    "Fillingstations Electricity Top 5": [
        [
            "Netherlands",
            66461
        ],
        [
            "France",
            45413
        ],
        [
            "Germany",
            43633
        ],
        [
            "Sweden",
            13564
        ],
        [
            "Italy",
            13214
        ]
    ],
    "Fast Charging": [
        [
            "2008",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2009",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2010",
            0
        ],
        [
            "2011",
            13
        ],
        [
            "2012",
            257
        ],
        [
            "2013",
            751
        ],
        [
            "2014",
            1474
        ],
        [
            "2015",
            3396
        ],
        [
            "2016",
            5190
        ],
        [
            "2017",
            8723
        ],
        [
            "2018",
            11138
        ],
        [
            "2019",
            15136
        ],
        [
            "2020",
            24987
        ]
    ],
    "Top 5 Countries Charging Positions Per 10 Evs": [
        [
            "Latvia",
            "3.15"
        ],
        [
            "Slovakia",
            "4.34"
        ],
        [
            "Croatia",
            "5.14"
        ],
        [
            "Estonia",
            "5.31"
        ],
        [
            "Netherlands",
            "5.71"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yea I looked at the network tab first and didn’t see anything. Good catch!

Comment: @joehoeller It should also be noted that the original `headers` and `params` have to be supplied to get a full, complete response from each endpoint. This can be accessed by right clicking on the request in the network settings and then choosing Copy > Copy as cURL

Comment: Because I didnt see that, I thought it was a doc ready issue from when the page loads vs when the charts are rendered. Which is still probably true if going after the data-* attr, but this feel more lightweight. Despite my solution working as well, although the JSON returned requires an addt'l step of mapping the cols as keys to the rows as values.

Comment: Thanks for posting this alternative solution! I know to look at the header info now.

Comment: @joehoeller I am glad you found it useful!

Comment: Actually I like the idea that both answers are here, because one could explore your solution, and use mine as a back up. Esp if the charts to be scraped are rendered statically/no api route/doc ready issues. As neither are "wrong", just solving for diff edge cases when scraping.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, this is an interesting problem that can actually trick many people when web scraping for data... The issue is that the chart is loaded after document ready in JavaScript, you can learn more about doc ready [here](https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/). But essentially, the charts are rendered after all the HTML, CSS and JS has loaded, and the data is bound to a data- attr.

I created a code example that uses NodeJS Express server to return the data in all of the charts in JSON. Essentially, it hits the URL, targets the class the charts are on, and then looks for the data-* attr that contains all the data of the chart. This way you will have working code to use and fork, if and when these situations arise with JavaScript based chart rendering.

**GitHub repo with NodeJS and Python solution:** https://github.com/joehoeller/dynamic-chart-parser-for-webscraping

Comment: love the JS solution, extremely useful.  Yes both of these solutions were correct, thank you for your input and NodeJS solution.